# Resolvers and Adapters

Tags: web-development, web-applications

In the web development application context, when someone says resolver, they talk about getting the data and modify it and then return it?

What about adapters? are adapters essentially resolver connecting data to a different formats? If you talk about database adapters, what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

In the networking context a resolver (a [DNS resolver](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/d/dns-resolver.htm) anyway) converts domain names into IP addresses. It does this by either finding the entry itself or by pointing you another DNS resolver. This is not a calculation. It's a lookup.

Adapters are typically a retro fit. `A` could have been designed for `B` but it wasn't. And so the `AtoBAdapter` is born to make round pegs fit in square holes.

And so it is with a database adapter. The database was designed by people who never heard of your project. So you either let the database dictate how you design your project or you hide it behind an adapter so your project can pretend it's never heard of the database. The adapter takes on the responsibility of knowing what your project means when it asks for stuff and how to ask for that from the database.

Now sure, there is a look up component to that. But that's the databases part of the job. The adapters focus shouldn't be on the lookup. It should be on providing an API into the database that is convenient for your app that doesn't expose database details.

Comment: In a web development context, in particular [in a GraphQL context](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/), a "resolver" can also be a kind of request handler.

Answer (score -1):

Well, Adapters implement the interface expected by the client and delegate the actual work to the adaptee. This pattern is generally used to integrate legacy systems with modern applications or to adapt third-party libraries to fit into an existing codebase.